# How to print libpari version in c?

Tags: c, versioning, pari

I would like to print version of libpari library from c program

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <mpc.h>
#include<pari/pari.h> 
int main(void){  
  
  gmp_printf ("MPFR library: %-12s\nMPFR header:  %s (based on %d.%d.%d)\n",
          mpfr_get_version (), MPFR_VERSION_STRING, MPFR_VERSION_MAJOR,
          MPFR_VERSION_MINOR, MPFR_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL);
  
  gmp_printf (" GMP-%s \n ", gmp_version );
  
  mpfr_printf(" MPC-%s \nMPFR-%s \n GMP-%s \n", MPC_VERSION_STRING, mpfr_version, gmp_version );
  
  gmp_printf("pari_version = %s\n",  GENtostr(pari_version())); //  paricfg_version_code);
  

return 0;
```

Program compiles but

```
gcc g.c -lpari -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp -Wall
a@zalman:~/Dokumenty/gmp$ ./a.out
MPFR library: 4.1.0       
MPFR header:  4.1.0 (based on 4.1.0)
 GMP-6.2.1 
  MPC-1.2.0 
MPFR-4.1.0 
 GMP-6.2.1 
Memory protection violation
```

I have tried also

```
pari_printf("pari_version = %Ps\n",  GENtostr(pari_version())); //  paricfg_version_code);
  pari_flush();
```

I have googled it and search the manual. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The reason you get a memory protection violation in the first attempt is because your program is lacking a `pari_init()` call; the function `pari_version()` needs the pari stack to create its return value there...

It should work in your main program, the one that actually uses the pari library and includes a `pari_init()` first. You might want to print the result as

```
    GEN v = pari_version(), M = gel(v,1), m = gel(v,2), p = gel(v,3);
    printf("pari-%ld.%ld.%ld", itos(M), itos(m), itos(p));
```

(M, m, p stand for Major version number, minor version number and patchlevel)

2. The second attempt using `pari_printf()` can't work for the same reason and also because you shouldn't then use `GENtostr()` because it converts the `GEN` to a `char*` and the `%Ps` construct expects a `GEN` argument.
3. If you *really* want it to work without the pari stack, you can adapt the solution in your answer by "decoding" the version code as follows

   ```
   const ulong mask = (1<<PARI_VERSION_SHIFT)-1;
   ulong n = paricfg_version_code, M, m, p;
   p = n & mask; n >>= PARI_VERSION_SHIFT;
   m = n & mask; n >>= PARI_VERSION_SHIFT;
   M = n;    
   printf("pari-%lu.%lu.%lu", M, m, p);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpfr.h>
#include <mpc.h>
#include<pari/pari.h> 
int main(void){  
  
  gmp_printf ("MPFR library: %-12s\nMPFR header:  %s (based on %d.%d.%d)\n",
          mpfr_get_version (), MPFR_VERSION_STRING, MPFR_VERSION_MAJOR,
          MPFR_VERSION_MINOR, MPFR_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL);
  
  gmp_printf (" GMP-%s \n ", gmp_version );
  
  mpfr_printf(" MPC-%s \nMPFR-%s \n GMP-%s \n", MPC_VERSION_STRING, mpfr_version, gmp_version );
  
  printf("paricfg_version_code = %ld\n",   paricfg_version_code);
  

return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
MPFR library: 4.1.0       
MPFR header:  4.1.0 (based on 4.1.0)
 GMP-6.2.1 
  MPC-1.2.0 
MPFR-4.1.0 
 GMP-6.2.1 
paricfg_version_code = 134401
```

Comment: is it better way ? using pari_printf ?